# iPhone form elements in HTML

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, css

I'm planning on recreating some fo the iPhone form elements in HTML/CSS but I'm assuming this already exists. I tried googling it but didn't find anything. Anybody seem something like this already in existence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might want to look at some of these toolkits:

[iUI](http://code.google.com/p/iui/)

[JQTouch](http://jqtouch.com/)

[iWebKit](http://iwebkit.net/)

All allow you to create an iPhone-like interface on a website.